# How to create and pass an array from KSH to Oracle sqlplus

Tags: arrays, loops, while-loop, sqlplus, ksh

I'm trying to create a KSH script in which I'm trying to create an array which will hold the contents of a text file, which contains a list of string values, and send the array to an SQL function in the KSH script. Here's what I've done so far:

```
export text_file=$HOME/values.log
while read **line**; 

       do
       CmResTypUpd 
   done < $text_file
```

The ResTypUpd does the following:

```
CmResTypUpd () {
            sqlplus -s $db_user/$db_pass@$db_inst <<EOF

            SET VERIFY OFF
            SET HEADING OFF
            SET PAGESIZE 200
            SET LINESIZE 200
            SET FEEDBACK OFF

            update My_Table set Column_Field_To_Change='NEW_VALUE' where IND1_COLUMN_VALUE='SomethingSomething' and IND2_COLUMN_VALUE='**$line**';
            commit;
   exit;

    EOF

            }
```

What I get is that the script hangs and does nothing.

Also, the script should be able to run cross-platform, meaning on any `Unix` or `Linux`.

Comment: you need to make your code more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your line as parameter to the function

```
export text_file=$HOME/values.log 
while read line; do CmResTypUpd "$line"; done < $text_file
```

And your function:

```
CmResTypUpd () {
    [...]
    update My_Table set Column_Field_To_Change='NEW_VALUE' 
    where IND1_COLUMN_VALUE='SomethingSomething' and IND2_COLUMN_VALUE='$1';
    [...]
}
```

And also the variable `**line**` should be `line`

Comment: Hi Majid, I tried to run it but still seemed stuck. so I debugged it and turns out the issue is in the calling of the var which holds the text file and its path. If I try to replace the text_file var with real value it works. I will try to run now the whole script with the log file value instead of its var but its weird, it should work with variable too, no?

Comment: Hi Majid,

Thanks very much :) it worked beautifully. About the other issue with the variable, I solved it by calling the text_file var into a new var and used the new var in the while loop.

Thanks again,

LW

Comment: yes it should work with variable too.. maybe your $HOME variable contains spaces or special characters ?